# UIScrollView w/ auto layout: Descendants are outside viewing area but view doesn't scroll

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, autolayout

I am trying to implement a scrollview, and while the easiest way to do this has always been to set contentSize, I am trying to do things “the right way” and my understanding is that it is now possible to do the entire thing in IB by pinning child views to the top/left/right/bottom edges.

I’ve done this and it really seems like it should be working. The bottom most subview is displayed off screen (see iOS 8 view debugging) and the constraints are all as I understand they should be, but the view still does not scroll. Per a lot of answers on SO, I have disabled the parent VC’s adjust scrollView insets property.

Attached images:

320px green bar is the subview which I thought would cause scrolling:
[320px green bar is the subview which I thought would cause scrolling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Wxjc.png)

Constraints for the scrollview and all child views:
[Constraints for the scrollview and all child views](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZGvqq.png)

Any thoughts about what is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it's confusing! The trick is to group all your controls into a single content view, and then connect your scroll view to that. Then, you just make sure the controls lay themselves out correctly relative to the content view, and it should all work out!

Oh, and make sure you implement viewForZoomingInScrollview and return the content view.